# Best way to handle error catching

Tags: c#, sql-server, error-handling, ado.net

I am creating an app which does some SQL server config, which part of a bigger system

There is a config table in the database of the system as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Config
(
    ConfigItem NVARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    ConfigValue NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO Config
VALUES
('LinkedServerName','MYLINKEDSERVER'),
('DatabaseName','APPLICATIONDATABASE')
```

My app is a Windows form with two textboxes and a button. The form also has an initially blank label which is used to display error messages to the user.

In the first text box, the value for the linked server name is shown, in the second, the value for the database is shown. Both are shown on form load.

On clicking the submit button, the two values are updated in the database based on what is in the text boxes.

I have the following code to populate the two textboxes with current values at form load:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // populate the textboxes
        txtLinkedServer.Text = GetConfigValue("LinkedServerName");
        txtDatabase.Text = GetConfigValue("DatabaseName");
    }

    private string GetConfigValue(string ConfigItem)
    {
        // get the value for the given config item from the database
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
            com.CommandText = "SELECT ConfigValue FROM Config WHERE ConfigItem = @ConfigItem";
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("ConfigItem", ConfigItem);
            com.Connection = conn;

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                dt.Load(com.ExecuteReader());

                if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    return "Error retrieving " + ConfigItem + " name from config table";
                }
                else
                {
                    return dt.Rows[0]["ConfigValue"].ToString();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return "Error in GetConfigValueMethod when retrieving " + ConfigItem;
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

If there is a problem with retrieving the config data (caught by the catch block in GetConfigValue) I want the label to show the string returned from GetConfigValue.

What is the best / neatest way to do this? I was thinking

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string message;
    // populate the textboxes
    try
    {
         message = GetConfigValue("LinkedServerName");
         txtLinkedServer.Text = message
    }
    catch
    {
         lblFeedback.Text = message;
    }
    // do the same for the database here
}
```

however, I cannot do that as I get

> Use of unassigned local variable 'Message'

Or am i best to change the GetConfigValue method so that it throws it's own exception in the catch block rather than returning a string and catching that in the Load method as follows;

```
private string GetConfigValue(string ConfigItem)    
{
    // get the value for the given config item from the database
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
             // same code here

        try
        {
            // same code here
        }
        catch
        {
            Throw new Exception ("Error in GetConfigValueMethod when retrieving " + ConfigItem);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // populate the textboxes
    try
    {
         txtLinkedServer.Text = GetConfigValue("LinkedServerName");

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         lblFeedback.Text = e.Message;
    }
    // do the same for the database here
}
```

Or some other way completely?

Comment: Try `string message = null;` to avoid the compile error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your second example, if that's the result you want, then it looks like you just need to replace

```
catch
{
     lblFeedback.Text = message;
}
```

in your first example with

```
catch (Exception e)
{
     lblFeedback.Text = e.Message;
}
```

from your second example.

Answer (score 0):

As error message says you tried to use unassigned variable 'message' and because of that you were getting that error.

Try this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string message = String.Empty;
// populate the textboxes
try
{
     message = GetConfigValue("LinkedServerName");
     txtLinkedServer.Text = message
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
        lblFeedback.Text = message;
     else
        lblFeedback.Text = ex.Message;

}
// do the same for the database here
```

}